# SharePoint page with Iframe showing error while sharing permissions

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, error, share, iframe

```
<iframe width="100%" id="fileViewer" src="https://abc.com.vn/library/Forms/AllItems.aspx" class="pdf-viewer-frame" height="900"></iframe>
```

Shared with dialog is not showing people picker

And on clicking `Cancel`, it gives error:

> No Renderer registered with id 1 at Object.Execute (clienttemplates.js:1)

[image]

Comment: Where did you use the iframe? you could provide your steps, so that I could try to reproduce it on my environment.

Comment: Hi Kally_MSFT. I use in page aspx with angular js

Answer (score 0):

Do you use a Classic page? I could reproduce this issue on a classic page with iframe enough that i don't use Angular js.

On a modern page, it could work well. This issue seems to just happen on classic pages.

For this issue, I suggest you use modern pages instead of classic ones, and also create a service request on Office 365 Admin Center to check if there is something wrong with Classic pages.

Comment: yes, I use a classic page. Thanks!